# Find what expression is the greatest between $R\rm{e}^{-S\rm{e}^{-Tx}}$ and $x$

Tags: inequality, exponential-function

I need to know what expression is the greatest between the following twos :

$R\textrm{e}^{-S\textrm{e}^{-Tx}}$ and $x$

$R$, $S$ and $T$ are strictly positive.

How can I determine it ? Thanks.

Comment: The first term is positive, so the answer is that it depends entirely on the relative magnitude of $Re^{-Se^{-Tx}}$ and $x$.

Comment: @AdrianKeister using relative magnitude, can we, depending on R S T values, know what expression is the greatest ?

Comment: Wait, you just **greatly** changed the problem. Is $x$ dividing or subtracting from the exponential term?

Comment: If $x$ divides, then the answer is simply that the sign of the whole expression equals the sign of $x$.

Comment: What I need is to know who is the greatest between $Re^{-Se^{èTx}}$ and $x$, I will reformulate my question

Comment: I would just plug the numbers into a calculator and call it a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the exponential function is monotonically increasing and $-x$ is monotoniclly decreasing, $Re^{-Se^{-Tx}}$ is monotonically increasing.  When $x=0, Re^{-Se^{-Tx}}=Re^{-S}.$  When $x \to \infty, Re^{-Se^{-Tx}}\to R$.  Of course, $x$ in increasing as well and generally much more quickly.  When $x=0$ it will be less than $Re^{-Se^{-Tx}}$ and by the time $x=R$ it will be greater.  Given values for $R,S,T$ you could solve $x=Re^{-Se^{-Tx}}$ numerically  to find the crossover point.  An example with $R=4,S=3,T=2$ is shown below. The intersection is barely below $x=4$
[image]